# How to apply @smoke tag to some of the tests when using the cypress-each plugin

Tags: cypress, cypress-grep

I'm using cypress-each to run dynamic tests, but the number of tests overall is large and I'd like to use cypress-grep to add @smoke tags to the data, and run a fraction of the tests.

How do I add tags to

```js
const title = (data) => `Testing ${data}`
it.each(data)(title, (data) => {})
```

I can use a function to customize the title, how can customize the options object?

This what I've tried,

```js
const title = (data) => `Testing ${data}`
it.each(data)(title, {tags: '@smoke'}, (data) => {})
```

but obviously it doesn't work - the smoke tag is applied to all test (added as example of tag syntax).

Comment: You can wrap the`it.each()` in a `describe()` and have the tag at the describe level.

Comment: No, the point is to only apply smoke tag to ***some*** of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can add tags dynamically to `cypress-each`.

But you could do it the [standard](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests/cypress/e2e/list-spec.cy.js) way if you wrap the data in objects.

```js
const data = [
  {value:'a', tag:'@smoke},            // only first will run when grepping @smoke
  {value:'b'}, 
  {value:'c'}
]

data.forEach(data => {
  const title = `Testing ${data}`
  const options = {tags: data.tag}    // when data.tag is undefined, 
                                      // effectively no tag applies 

  it(title, options, (data) => {
    ...
  })
})
```